# Dividing two columns in R

Tags: r, datatable, operators, arithmetic-expressions

I have a .txt data file and I want to perform a very simple operation, namely creating a vector/column with values that are created by dividing a column of the .txt by another column of the .txt.

It seems very trivial but I haven't found out how to do this. First I encountered problems with the `type` of entries. Being non-numeric I created a for-loop making them all numeric but even after that I didn't succeed. Therefore I now ask the question from stratch.

My text file looks like this:

```
state drivers cars pop
AK 360 5.1 5877 
AL 498 34.4 3942 
AR 219 19.2 3585 
AZ 728 31.3 7116 
CA 6539 336.2 6518
```

Now I just want to make a column (does not have to be included in the already existing table, can be just a new variable) with the values of column 2 divided by the values of column 3 divided by 10.

So far I just read the table as:

```
crimedata <- read.table("drivers.txt",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

How to do this simple operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do

```
crimedata$newcol <- with(crimedata, drivers/cars * 10)
```

Comment: I assume we change df1 into crimedata? I then get the error: `drivers not found`

Comment: @Mathbeginner  Based on the data showed, 'drivers' is one of the column names, right?  Can you check `str(crimedata)`

Comment: I guess it is a value in the table itself. For example `crimetable[1,2]` returns  `drivers`

Comment: @Mathbeginner  Can you check `colnames(crimetable)`

Comment: it returns `V1, V2 ,..`. I think I found what I did wrong! When I add `headers=T` in the read.table(), it does give headers!

Comment: @Mathbeginner  You need to do `read.table("drivers.txt",stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header = TRUE)` while reading .  Otherwise, it will think that the column names are the first row

Comment: Thank you so much. This was exactly what was wrong. Took me way too long to figure this out. Your help is much appreciated!